# How do I dribble using the keyboard while playing FIFA 12 on PC?

Tags: pc, fifa-12

I'm playing FIFA 12 on PC, and I can't figure out how on earth it is possible to dribble.

Can somebody help me understand how it is possible to perform skill moves using a keyboard instead of a joystick?

Comment: Do you mean just running with the ball or actually executing skill moves like step-overs etc?

Answer (score 1):

This May Help